# How to use named parameters / named prepared statements with Postgres and ADODB

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, adodb

I am cleaning up some legacy asp-vba code that talks to a Postgres database (8.2) over ADODB. At the moment it's using string building for SQL statements and obviously I'd like to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

I cannot work out how to do this with a named variable. I've only succeeded in doing it with the "?" operator and adding the parameters in the order they are defined in the SQL. This is no good in my situation[1].

I have been able to do simple some simple parameter replacement using the ? operator and CreateParameter(...):

```
var oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield = ? AND another = ?";
oCmd.Parameters.Append oCmd.CreateParameter("", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "val1")
oCmd.Parameters.Append oCmd.CreateParameter("", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "val2")
```

But if I attempt to do it with names then it *DOES NOT* work:

```
var oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somefield = @a AND another = @b";
oCmd.Parameters.Append oCmd.CreateParameter("@b", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "val2")
oCmd.Parameters.Append oCmd.CreateParameter("@a", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "val1")
```

I see some notes saying it might actually be a failing of ODBC (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/231217/Parameters-SqlCommand-vs-OledbCommand-and-OdbcComm). Does anyone know a way around this or some other option?

[1] Unfortunately I cannot use ? ? ? and define the parameters in order. The code is already wrapped up in a legacy ORM that will sub the values in out of order. If I can send them by name then I can do this cleanly.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm still looking for a 'proper' way to do this. In my own case however my workaround was:
Just before SQL is executed, parse through the SQL string finding @replacement tags, then substituting a ?, and creating a parameter.
This way the arguments were created in order. But it's hacky. And I also had to guess at when numeric values should be substituted.

Comment: It may be a driver issue.  My recommendations are to check which driver you are using, look at the options, and contact the driver developers.  You will probably get a lot more mileage out of that approach than here unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I once had to modify the postgres driver of adodb (release 2004) to make it capable of handing both parameters and using of regular expressions in postgres statements. The problem was that using the "?" question character is always interpreted as a parameter. So I modified the Postgres 7 driver on the **_query** method, changing line 151 as:

```
$sqlarr = explode(' ?',trim($sql));
```

Just adding a space before the question mark. The ' ?' are replaced by the driver with $1, $2, etc., so, may be you anticipate this replacement sending this named parameters $1, $2 instead of the "?".

Abrazo

Comment: Thanks Abrazo. Unfortunately I do not have access to this system at the moment (it is still running), so I'm unable to verify if this would work. But it sounds promising.